# Why does Xcode12 give me SQLite Compiler Error?

Tags: xcode, ios14, sqlite.swift

After upgrading to Xcode 12 / iOS 14 my project is no longer compiling/importing the SQLite3 library because it is previously defined in the iOS 14 usr/include.

[image: SQLLite previously defined here]

Is this something that I can fix in my build settings? Can I remove it from the usr/include?

The project uses a mix of ObjC/Swift, CocoaPods is bringing in SQLite.swift

Comment: Please give your solution as an Answer, not as an edit on the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found a temporary solution by using an experimental branch for this CocoaPod. Anyone else experiencing this problem should try:

pod 'SQLite.swift/standalone', :git => 'https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift', :branch => 'master'